# Can I add additional background attribute to subclass?

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I have a CSS file that has code looking like this...

```
.button{
    width: 700px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Gauge;
    color: white;
    border: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 11px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    transition: 0.4s
}

button.oneshot{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed,
                url("oneshot.png") center 60%;

button.lisatp{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed,
                url("lisa the painful.jpg") 45% 60%;
}
...
...
```

As you can see, there is a line that is repeated in the subclasses **oneshot** and **lisatp**:

```
linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed
```

However, since each subclass also has an image as the background as well, I can't find a way to place the repeated line in `.button`.

Is it possible to somehow simplify this even more, or is this as simple as it is going to get?

Comment: Yes, you can, you will need to use multiple backgrounds.
 Note tho, it is not supported by all browsers!
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: @GhostPengy you may notice that he's already using multiple background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variable to simplify this then you will be able to easily change the gradient for all the element of each one individually:

```css
.button{
    width: 700px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Gauge;
    color: white;
    border: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 11px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    --grad:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background:var(--grad);
}

.button.oneshot{
    background:var(--grad),url("https://lorempixel.com/400/200/") center 60%;
}

.button.lisatp{
    background: var(--grad),url("https://lorempixel.com/300/200/") 45% 60%;
}

.button.new-grad{
    --grad:linear-gradient(rgba(0,190,0,1),rgba(0,190,0,0.4),rgba(0,180,0,1)) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background: var(--grad),url("https://lorempixel.com/300/200/") 45% 60%;
}
```

```html
<span class="button"></span>
<span class="button oneshot"></span>
<span class="button lisatp"></span>
<span class="button new-grad"></span>
```

Comment: CSS variables would be the best use here. However, they are not supported by all browsers, so check your targets before using it.

Comment: @GhostPengy only IE fail to the support https://caniuse.com/#search=variables .. so for me it's supported by every browser as i don't mind about IE ;)

Comment: CSS variables are supported only since IE15, it is not supported by several other browsers too. On quick estimate, you will not support around 6% of the userbase. I am just giving heads up. https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: @GhostPengy yes i know this and since it's IE, i don't mind :) .. so we should force the 6% to use new more powerfull borwser and leave old-dying-no-more-supported browser like IE ;) you may not agree but i think like this :)

Comment: Yes and no. It comes down to hardware. For example Opera mini and Samsung, browsers are hardware locked. Meaning without getting a new device you cannot really upgrade it. Should we force that user?

Comment: @GhostPengy if you insist to convince me [and you will not ;) ] why not providing a solution that is supported everywhere ? :)  ... for me we need to think about the future and go straight forwards. The new powerfull features are here, well supported by modern browsers so yes we should force the 3% of people using old Devices to change their devices too ! what's is the cost of a basic android device nowadays ? nothing ... so for me no need to waste time satisfying 6% of people that are stack to old stuff, one day they should evolve.